# image not showing in UIImage from cached data

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nsmutablearray, nscache

I cant possibly get the image that i parsed from the XML to show on my `UIImageView` using the code below. Am I doing something wrong because I checked it using `NSLog` to show if there is a link and apparently there is.

```
NSString *imageURL = [currentData.imageLink];
NSLog(@"this is link = %@", imageURL);
[cachedList addObject:imageURL];
[myCache setObject:cachedList forKey:@"imageURL"];
cachedList = [myCache objectForKey:@"imageURL"];  /where cachedList is NSMutableArray

for(id obj in cachedList){
    NSLog(@"value = %@", obj); //to show value
    cell.imageShow.image = [UIImage imageNamed:obj];
 }
```

and also I tried doing the below code, but it gives me an error.

```
 if (cachedList != nil) {
     cell.imageShow.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[cachedList valueForKey:@"imageURL"]];
 }
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: nothing. the imageview just show blank or white

Comment: Try type casting.
 cell.imageShow.image = [UIImage imageNamed:(NSString *)obj];

Comment: tried it but still the same and the thing is i should only have 7 values parsed but im having is 14 means its doubled. And what i did here is allocate the string data into my cache and then set the NSMutableArray with the value from that cached data.

Comment: @AceMunim Did you actually download the images and then store them in cache? Or are you just storing the url's in a dictionary called `myCache`?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using UITableView then this is the thing i have used and i prefer for tableview

Link: https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache